# Is there an injective homomorphism on the Turing degrees?

Tags: computability-theory, turing-degrees

I know that the existence of a non-trivial automorphism of the Turing degrees is a long-standing open problem. I am curious to know if something is known about (non-trivial) injective homomorphisms (of the Turing degrees within themselves). In other words, is there a substructure of the Turing degrees which is isomorphic to the Turing degrees?

Comment: This is true under CH: Sacks proved that every locally countable partial order of size $\omega_1$ embeds into the Turing degrees. Under CH, we can use this to get an embedding of the Turing degrees plus an extra point (incomparable to everything else) into the Turing degrees. The extra point ensures that the embedding is nontrivial.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question, but let me argue that one can add such an injective homomorphism (for the ground-model degrees) by forcing.

The argument relies on the fact that the Turing degree order is universal for countable orders, and indeed for countable upper semi-lattices. For example, see

- Antonio Montalbán, [Embeddings into the Turing degrees](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eantonio/papers/Tdegrees.pdf), 2007.

Every countable upper semi-lattice embeds into the Turing degrees.

Fix a copy of a countably universal partial order inside $\mathcal{D}$, one for which every countable order embeds into it by a back-and-forth argument.

Consider now the forcing extension $V[G]$ in which the continuum and hence also the set of Turing degrees $\mathcal{D}$ is made countable. By performing the back-and-forth argument in $V[G]$, but using the now-countable structure of ground model degrees $\mathcal{D}^V$, we can map $\mathcal{D}^V$ into itself in an order-preserving manner, realizing the embedding in $V[G]$.